# How to tell if the current section is defined in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer, conditionals

I am customising the footer of my Beamer slides. The footer displays the title of the slides, followed by a ":", and then the current section title. This works fine if the current section is defined. However, if the section is not defined, I am left with the current title followed by a dangling colon. I would like the colon not to be displayed if the current section is not defined.

So, how do I determine if the current slide's section is defined, and how do I use this in a conditional in the footer? For completeness, it would also be helpful to know how one would determine if the current subsection is defined.

My attempt so far:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.85\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{author in head/foot}%
   \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
   \hspace*{2ex}\insertshorttitle  % insert title in footer       
   \, : \insertsection             % insert current section [should only be done if section defined] 
\end{beamercolorbox}%

% more code to insert the slide number in the footer (not shown)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If no previous `\section` exists `\insertsection` is simply empty (at least in my tests). So you could test for this using:

```
\ifx\insertsection\empty
     % it is empty
\else
    it is not
\fi
```

Applied to your code:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.85\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{author in head/foot}%
   \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
   \hspace*{2ex}\insertshorttitle  % insert title in footer       
   \ifx\insertsection\empty\else
      \, : \insertsection             % insert current section [should only be done if section defined] 
   \fi
 \end{beamercolorbox}%
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This works perfectly! For subsections, you can simply apply the conditional to \insertsubsection.

Comment: In your first code block there is an `\if` instead of a `\fi`.