# beamer headline

Tags: beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell if the current section is defined in Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/how-to-tell-if-the-current-section-is-defined-in-beamer)

I am creating a document with latex beamer with a document structure like this:

```
\section{First section}
  \subsection{sub A}  X
  \subsection{sub B}
\section{Second section} XX
```

I have been trying to create a headline that will display the following at X

```
1 First section        1.1 sub A
```

But the following at XX

```
2 Second section
```

To achieve this, I have attempted to set the headline template as follows (note, this will produce some warnings but I have omitted some lay-out options for the sake of brevity)

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \thesection\insertsection \hfill \thesection.\thesubsection~\insertsubsection
}
```

This works as planned at X, but at XX it produces

```
2 Second section        2.0
```

I am looking for a solution to this problem that will somehow omit the subsection numbering when not in a subsection.

I've been trying to create an "if" control structure that will do something else if the subsection name is empty but nothing seems to work as I hoped.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/how-to-tell-if-the-current-section-is-defined-in-beamer It appears this post solves all of my problems, of cours I will stumble upon it seconds after posting a question. I'm not sure if I should delete my post or not, I'll leave it to a moderator to do what he thinks is appropriat.

Comment: Great that the other post helped! So I will close this question as a duplicate, thank you for the information.

Comment: Please consider choosing a better username. 'Myself' could be confusing if other people like to refer to you.